# How to get document library in webpart property using no javascript in spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-custom-property-pane

I am trying to get document library in webpart property using no javascript in spfx. How can I retrieve in drop-down.

Comment: What do you mean by "no JavaScript"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PropertyFieldListPicker, it's supposed to allow you to pick up one list (event document library) from a dropdown.

https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldListPicker/

Hope this helps, but when you said "no javascript" I get confused.

Comment: I'm assuming that "using no javascript in spfx" means that "No JavaScript framework" was selected when the SPFx Yeoman Generator asked "Which framework would you like to use?".  The PnP Reusable property pane controls will work with projects created using both "No JavaScript framework" and "React".

Comment: If @RobWindsor is right, then this picker will do the job. Just use the template 100 or 101 based on what you needs.